# Is there any better way to re-render Native Component after Android view is updated

Tags: android, react-native

I have a native component view passing from Android to RN through                         `createViewInstance`
.It is rendered perfectly. However, when I added a child view to it during run-time in native side, the child is never rendered.

I have to call     `requestLayout()` ,     `invalidate()`   in native side to make the child shown. Sometimes I need extra handling for the size of native view as it has been set to be 0.
Is there any better way to force RN to re-render the native component?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your native view component.

```
@Override
  public void requestLayout() {
    super.requestLayout();
    post(measureAndLayout);
  }

  private final Runnable measureAndLayout =
      new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          measure(
              MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
              MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
          layout(getLeft(), getTop(), getRight(), getBottom());
        }
      };
```